# Unable to center material-ui GridList

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, material-ui

I have a `GridList` which I am using to display `Cards`. These components are styled as follows:

> card.js

```
const useStyles = makeStyles({
    card: {
        maxWidth: 240,
        margin: 10
    },
    media: {
        height: 100
    }
})
```

> grid.js

```
const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
    root: {
        display: 'flex',
        flexWrap: 'wrap',
        justifyContent: 'space-around',
        overflow: 'hidden'
    },
    gridList: {
        width: '80%',
        height: '100%'
    }
}))

export default function CardGridList() {
const classes = useStyles()

return (
    <div className={classes.root}>
        <GridList className={classes.gridList} cols={4}>
            <CardItem />
            <CardItem />
            <CardItem />
            <CardItem />
            <CardItem />
            <CardItem />
            <CardItem />
            <CardItem />
        </GridList>
    </div>
    )
}
```

> and finally, container.js (which uses `styled-components`)

```
const ContainerWrapper = styled.div`
    margin: 0 auto;
`

export default class Container extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <ContainerWrapper>
                <ThickSpace />
                <CardGridList />
            </ContainerWrapper>
        )
    }
}
```

However, no matter what combination of properties I try, I cannot get the cards to align in the center. I am always left with something like this:

[image]

Where the `GridList` is skewed off-center. I have gone through the `material-ui` documentation, looked at numerous explanations like [this](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-center-things-with-style-in-css-dc87b7542689/), but nothing is working. Please help!

Comment: what is `ThickSpace`? sounds like a culprit for a weird spacing issue :)

Comment: sorry, @JohnRuddell it is just an empty component with a fixed height used for spacing, I should have clarified

Comment: why dont you just use css grid for your spacing?

Comment: @JohnRuddell I wanted to try out the material-ui `GridList`, no other reason. I will probably end up switching if this doesn't work out

Comment: well, you dont specify a max-width on your parent `ContainerWrapper` so its essentially full width, you'd need to set it to be a max width that matches the size of 4 cards side by side, that would center it. `max-width: 1040px;` i think

Comment: @JohnRuddell honestly, as per your suggestion I quickly tried out the css grid and it worked perfectly, I would accept it as an answer if it weren't a comment

Comment: ill make it an answer for you :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You specify `margin: 0 auto;` on the top level container element, however you don't give the element any styles that make this auto margin take effect. You need to give a width gate for the element, so that way the auto margin will actually space on either side.

```
const ContainerWrapper = styled.div`
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width: 1040px;
`
```

I got 1040 from the size of the card you defined. 240 width and 10 margin on each side means 20 px of space (first card 10px on right, second card 10px on the left). `260 * 4 = 1040` :)